# Issues with reading from file using a loop

Tags: java, twilio

I'm currently having problems with reading phone numbers from a text file, then having them loop through the list of phone numbers and send out text messages using Twilio.

```
String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACCOUNT_SID"; 
String AUTH_TOKEN = "AUTH_TOKEN";
String fileName = "phoneNumbers.txt";
String line = null;
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
try
{
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", line));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+TWILIO_NUMBER")); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "TEST: Test message, please ignore."));
        MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
        Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
        System.out.println(message.getTo() + " " + message.getBody()); 
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    System.out.println("All messages sent.");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Unable to open file.");
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Error reading file.");
}   catch (TwilioRestException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(alert.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

This is the output that I have been getting:

```
+PHONE_NUMBER_ONE
+PHONE_NUMBER_ONE Sent from your Twilio trial account - TEST: Test message, please ignore.
+PHONE_NUMBER_TWO
+PHONE_NUMBER_ONE Sent from your Twilio trial account - TEST: Test message, please ignore.
All messages sent.
```

I am able to read both phone numbers using System.out.println(line), but the program won't read it when I add it to the params.add line. Is there something wrong with my loop, and how do I fix it?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seem you missed to clear `params` , add `params.clear()` in your while loop

Comment: I would suggest clearing your `params` at the beginning of your loop. Looks like it's retaining information. Not sure how the message factory works but that's not really an ideal set up for key-value pairing. 
You should be using a **HashMap**.

Comment: Added params.clear(), and now everything's working as it should. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Added `params.clear()` to the end of the while loop, and now everything's working as it should. Thanks so much for the help